# Week number and ISO 8601 for Pageview counters

Tags: asp.net, mysql, datetime, iso8601

I need to store page view for specific products by week, day and year.  I thought about using the following tables:

### Weekly

- List item
- id
- product_id
- week_number
- year
- total_page_views (counter)

### Daily

- product_id
- total_page_views

[for the day I won't keep archive data and yearly will be calculated based on the weekly table]

My question is actually about the week numerical value.  I am wondering which week number I should use, I've read that ISO 8601 is one option and using .NET DataTime function to get the week is another one. I need your help to know which one should I use and whether there is a better way to optimize the table.

At the end, I want to show the top viewed products for the previous week, this week, previous year, etc.

I target my app towards the US and Europe crowd, where the week start at Monday. I'm developing my application in C#/ASP.NET/MySQL/Entity Framework. THANKS.

Comment: please dont. Save the view with the timestamp(+product_id) and let your application/view do the work for you instead. The summing of your pageviews will take some time then, but ohterwhise each view would have to update the daily and weekly table. Rather let some jobs run at night and sum those up and save them to temp tables for fast data retrvial

Comment: Where to save the view with timestamp, to the db or a application variable?, sorry I don't follow